# GPS Coords being always 0.0-0.0 using LocationListener in a Android App

Tags: java, android, gps

I need to develop an app for android for a university task and a part of it consists in sending the GPS coords of the device to my database. Here's the class that I'm using to get the coords

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

double latitude;
double  longitude;


public MyLocationListener(Context myContext){
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
}

public  double getLatitude(){
    return latitude; }

public  double getLongitude(){
    return longitude; }

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   latitude =  location.getLatitude();
    longitude =  location.getLongitude();

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

That is called inside InterfaceActivity.java, using this:

```
        MyLocationListener ggwp = new MyLocationListener(InterfaceActivity.this);
    HttpDevices elenco = new HttpDevices(LoginIstance.getIst().getLog()[0],LoginIstance.getIst().getLog()[1],LoginIstance.getIst().getID(),String.valueOf(ggwp.getLatitude()),String.valueOf(ggwp.getLongitude()));
```

And finally HttpDevices is an asynttask that "runs" http messages to my database, using this code:

```
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://88.116.86.82/android/remote/connessione.php?user="+usr+"&pass="+pss+"&id="+id+"&lat="+lat+"&long="+log);
```

But the coords send to the database are always 0.0 - 0.0 , and I can't even try the code an debug it on the emulator ( blue stack ) because it doesn't have gps coords. Tried it on my Moto G but they are just 0. I tried spamming that string (connessione.php etc.. ) in my broweser giving random values for lat and long and yes, it works. It updates the database and shows the coords in my app, so the problem should be in the java. Any tips? I've searched alot in google/stackoverflow and didnt' find anything, it's the first time I encouter a problem that requires me to post here. Hope you can help me! Thank youu!

Edit: in case you want to take a look at my whole code there is a github link:
https://github.com/leejaku/RemoteAndroid2

Comment: Take a look at my Screenshot... Your App / my listener is working, but your device has just no Location, and needs long to get the current location, but it works... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just try to get through your code... Please correct me if I have missed something

If I look at your HttpDevices Class you try to send your Data like this...

```
lat = String.valueOf(MyLocationListener.latitude);
log = String.valueOf(MyLocationListener.longitude);
```

This will try to get the value of a class property which is 0.0, because it is not the instance of MyLocationListener that is updating the lat and long... you need to create a Singleton of MyLocationListener to get one single sharedInstance of your listener, or you have to do it with a Delegate Pattern, or you save the Values to SharedPreferences...

Do you have enough knowledge of Java to build one of these Paradigms, and does it make sense to you? (Sorry for that Question, I don't know how good you are mate :-)...) Otherwise I could write you something to solve it

**UPDATE**

Well this problem seems to be nasty, so we will need a "NastyLocationListener" to solve it, and thank Neo has written the ultimate one ;-)

Checkout this Class
https://gist.github.com/DennisWeidmann/de2ebb2b2549a938fa50

Usage just like this

```
/////////Just to know it
        Log.e("lati", NastyLocationListener.getLatitude(this)); //On most phones you can use the Listener without any other Code
        Log.e("longi", NastyLocationListener.getLongitude(this)); //It uses Androids native cached location but this is not updated proper
        /////////Just to know it end

        /////////Normal usage
        nastyLocationListener = new NastyLocationListener(this); //In your MainActivity instanciate a NastyLocationListener (its only needed once... All other Activities could get data from him)
        nastyLocationListener.startListening(); //It starts listening to Location Updates and triggers the Location Provider to fetch updates (its bool, true if almost one Provider is available, false if no Provider is available)

        nastyLocationListener.stopListening(); //Use this line when you pause the app, or quit it... it will stop the listener and could be resumed with startListening()

        NastyLocationListener.getLatitude(this); //Could be used in every class, on every time, however you want without any other code like above
        NastyLocationListener.getLongitude(this); //Could be used in every class, on every time, however you want without any other code like above
        /////////Normal usage end
```

**UPDATE**

Screenshot of your App on my device without changing any code instead of the REST Call, I have inserted a Log to output my Latitude..

[image]

Comment: My bad, I didn't update the project on github :( can you check it again please? Anyway yeah, I know what a singleton or a design pattern is, and thank you for your kindness and time

Comment: Ok, I will take a look on your updated code tomorrow, could you write me a comment to this comment as a reminder? So when I open my StackOverflow tomorrow I will see your red flag on top... Otherwise its possible that I forget it... And if you solve this problem until then, please write me a short info ok?

Comment: I didn't solve it yet,here's your reminder! I'll try the code of the guy above you anyway

Comment: Thanks for the reminder... I just looked at your updated code, now it doesn't set latitude and longitude nowhere?!? :-) I will give you a nerdy dirty workaround... :-) give me a second

Comment: Hey I don't wanna bother you, but you seem so nice and kind, maybe you wanna help me on skype? :) in that case that's my  contact: calannap

Comment: No problem man, we won't need Skype, I have written you the "NastyLocationListener", solving your problem... Just put it into your Projekt and follow my Usage instructions...

Comment: Oh and please tell me shortly if its working for you or not... I have just tested it once on my Google Nexus 5 and it worked like a charm :-)

Comment: It isn't working :( I commited the code on github if you want to see it

Comment: I started by writing the startlistening in my mainActivity as you can see,then I uses the get latitude on then I used getLat and getLon on my InterfaceActivity when creating the HttpDevices object

Comment: yes, that should be working... what happened? You don't posted a result of this test? :-)

Comment: The startListening() method also returns a boolean, if any of the location provider is listening... is it true or false after launch? And on most Android Devices it is depending on GPS / Network Connection, how fast you get a current Location... So if getLong() is null, there is no Location currently :-)

Comment: In your HTTPDevices, your properties are still static, please delete the static modifier public String lat="0"; public String log="0";

Comment: I have just downloaded your project, loaded it with my AndroidStudio, commented everything out to get directly to your InterfaceActivity and Logged the Value that should be sent by lat...

Comment: 08-26 21:02:23.252    8757-8822/com.example.lee.remote_android E/lat﹕ 50.31030024

Comment: it worked in your project, without modifying anything :-) Dude your Android Device doesn't have a location present, at the time you are making the HTTPDevices Call... Just give it some time and it will work perfectly :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this class, it's from my github account: https://github.com/chiiiky14/GPStracker

Import it to your project and create the object:

```
GPSTracker gpstracker = new GPSTracker(context);
```

And after that:

```
  gpstracker.getLatitude();
  gpstracker.getLongitude();
```

Just make sure the GPS of your device is already activate. Hope this will help.